# Start a process : difference between Console Application and WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I would like to run a GUI program with command-line arguments which process a text by adding some xml tags. So the text has to be on the filesystem and the xml is created in the same directory. I tried both : a console application and a Web Service. Why the WS does not work? How can I debug it?

This code works as I want :

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    private static void ExecuteConsoleApp(string filepath)
    {
      string dir = @"E:\temp\";

      ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
      startInfo.FileName = dir + @"App.exe";
      startInfo.Arguments = "EN /R /U /F\"" + filepath + "\"";

      Debug.WriteLine(startInfo.FileName + " " + startInfo.Arguments);

      using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
      {
         exeProcess.WaitForExit(5000); // Wait a while
         exeProcess.Kill(); // Then kill 
      }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      ExecuteConsoleApp(@"E:\temp\temp.txt");
    }
  }
}
```

Why this one does not? I mean that the process is created in Session ID=0, but no GUI and no xml: I do not know what is happening...

```
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace WCF_Exalead
{
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
  public class Service : IService
  {
    public void GetXml()
    {
      ExecuteConsoleApp(@"E:\temp\temp.txt");
    }

    private static void ExecuteConsoleApp(string filepath)
    {
      string dir = @"E:\temp\";

      ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
      startInfo.FileName = dir + @"App.exe";
      startInfo.Arguments = "EN /R /U /F\"" + filepath + "\"";

      Debug.WriteLine(startInfo.FileName + " " + startInfo.Arguments);

      using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
      {
         exeProcess.WaitForExit(5000); // Wait a while
         exeProcess.Kill(); // Then kill 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE: The only difference between both run is that App.exe runs in the first code with SessionID=1 when the second runs with SessionId=0.

Comment: What account is the hosting application pool running as?

Comment: @JohnRasch it is "DefaultAppPool" for the Web Service. And my window account for the standalone app.

Comment: Why are you using `.CreateNoWindow = false;` - try with true

Comment: @NSGaga - yeah that might be helpful if the intention is to see a window! @enguerran - Also, you won't ever see the window if it's not running under your account anyway. It must also have the ability to interact with the desktop. As for how to debug this, in VS choose the "Attach to Process..." menu item under the Debug menu and select w3wp.exe - then you can set a breakpoint before you start the process. I would also note that in your `while` loop you are pegging the CPU, at the *very least* add a `Thread.Sleep(50)` in the loop.

Comment: @JohnRasch - actually the 'intention' is to 'CreateNoWindow' - so 'CreateNoWindow = true' - OP is using the 'false' (that's not my code, I said try the 'true')

Comment: @NSGaga - Agreed. Reading it again, it appears the tone of my comment was not captured very well, it was meant to be more disbelief that I had missed something that obvious :)

Comment: @JohnRasch - you are right about the `while` loop, that was a "quick and dirty" code. I did not try to attach the process to debug `App.exe` because I did not have the source. But I am quite sure it is due to incorrect rights or session matter or something about the administration of the OS. @NSGaga - I confess that I did a Cargo Cult : I copied/pasted a code with a great faith to see it working. Thanks for your help, I keep working on this.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't how web services work. The names "Web Service" and "Windows Service" are indeed very similar, but they are very different types of application.

A web service has no UI. It is an application that sits on a web server and exposes methods. You can call these methods over http using various communication protocols, such as SOAP, and they will return data.

This article explains how to work with web services, if you are so inclined. [Introduction to Web Services](http://blog.psychocoder.net/2011/04/03/introduction-to-net-web-services/)

Comment: I am talking about Web Service. And I (my boss) want to start the process of an UI app which takes commandline arguments... My question is detailed and it is not about how to write a Web Service.